# notification popup when new data is added to the DataGridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am building a standalone application with MS Access as the database. When I update the data from the application, I want the data in the DataGridView to also be updated on all of the other computers that are running the application. For that I have `LoadData()` but when a new ROW is added I am not getting the notification popup.
I really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance. I am not a pro in coding.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        LoadData()
    End Sub

Private Sub dgvNotify_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles dgvNotify.RowsAdded
    Dim targetRow = Me.dgvNotify.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().OrderByDescending(Function(r) r.Cells("ID").Value).FirstOrDefault
    If targetRow IsNot Nothing Then
        targetRow.Selected = True
        New_Notification()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.Visible = False
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub New_Notification()
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "New Important Notification"
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Open the notification application to check the notifications" & vbCrLf & "If you have any question reachout to ops leads:)"
    NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000)
End Sub
```

Comment: is in loaddata the datagridview updated?

Comment: You don't need `If targetRow IsNot Nothing Then...` The event occurs whenever a new row or punch of rows is/are added to the grid. Get the index of the first inserted row from the `.RowIndex` property and the number of rows have been added from the `e.RowCount` property. In short, always call the `New_Notification()` method in there.

Comment: Yes @nbk the Loaddata() have updated the datagridview, I am not getting notification when a new row is added to the datagrid view.

Comment: @dr.null I will try it out and keep posted, Thank you.

Comment: @dr.null Please help me with the script, I am unable to follow your steps.

Comment: Sure, what do you need to do in `dgvNotify_RowsAdded` event? Now, comment all lines in this event except `New_Notification()` and try. Is that accepted or you need also to select the inserted row(s). Please clarify.

Comment: @Eragon006: I've updated your post to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Please ensure that my update to your post accurately describes what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you! I am trying to popup a notification to all the machines where my application is installed, for that I have set a timer to refresh the database, but I am not getting a notification on when a new row is added to DataGrid view. I could be wrong with Rows added, 
my thought, I have a Primary Key column that is ID in a increment numbers, so what if I count the number of rows in a label and whenever the number increased it should trigger a notification?

Comment: @user9938 I am trying to show a popup notification when a new row is added to the datagridview on a standalone form.

Comment: ah OK. No this approach won't work then. Events handlers are application-wide mechanism. Even if you have two instances of your app running in the same machine, one app does not know anything about handling events in another. You need to deal with the Database in the Timer to track the changes and update the view accordingly.

Comment: @dr.null I got the numbering and it worked and reflects on another machine that I have installed on to; Now I need to figure out when the number increments, I would like to get a notification will that be possible?

Comment: When the `RowsAdded` is raised, that means new row(s) has/have been added and the current grid's `RowCount` property has been incremented as well. In short, and again, always call `New_Notification()`. And just in case you mean something else. Keep the `RowCount` in a class field, and use it elsewhere in your code to compare the current value of the property and the last assigned one.